# How to run code on VS Code using C/C++ Windows package

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I code in C language, I installed the C/C++ package...

I use VS Code to replace Code::Blocks.

When I use the command to run the code it works fine the first time then when I want to modify my code I use the same command (run code) I got a message the code is already running even though I closed the console.

Comment: It's unclear for me. You are running the code from VS Code?

Comment: Yes, I run the code from there by using the little play icon in the upper right corner. The problem is that I got a message " Code is already running" message that appears in the bottom right corner...

Comment: Ok problem solved ! I was using the extension Code Runner, this message was because I didn't stopped the running code by pressing the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+M and it was requied to stop the code to run it after again if I wanted to ... :) Thanks anyway

Comment: Great! You can answer your own question here to help others learn from the problem :)